# How to to get a concrete class from an hierarchical database structure

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design

This is my database structure:

[image]

I have an `AbstractUser` table for common properties of my role tables: `Nurse`, `Doctor` or other roles may be added in the future.

I also get an `Event` table which use abstract_user_id as the fk.

I can easily get the associated `AbstractUser` of an `Event`, the question is how can I get the concrete class of that `AbstractUser`, the only way I can come up with is go through the role tables(nurse, doctor, and more), and use the fk(abstract_user_id) in those tables to check if `AbstractUser.id` exist.

Is there any better way to do this?

I ask for better ways cause seems I have to do this every time when I need a concrete class from `AbstractUser`, and I cannot put this into a method cuz the return type is not determined. Repeat this everywhere makes me feel a code smell:

```
AbstractUser absUser = event.getAbsUser();

if(existInNurseTable(absUser)){
   Nurse n = getNurseByAbsUser(absUser);
   ...
   //business logic
}else if(...){
   ...
}else{
   ...
}
```

Comment: SQL was invented before OO.  It is painful to try to shoehorn OO into database structures.